# Html.DisplayNameFor not show data (.net mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Run MODEL that I submit to View.

```
public class Run
{
    public List<Car> cars{get; set;}
    public Bike bike{get; set;}
}

public class Car
{
    public name  {get; set;}
    public Model {get; set;}
}

public class Bike
{
    public name  {get; set;}
    public Model {get; set;}
}
```

In my view I want to show List of car names.

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cars.Name)
```

In table header I am trying this.

This is not working. It says something reference missing?!

In my View I am able to show all MODEL data. BUT I just can't show Heading text

In my view I also have

```
@using //Namespace to model folder
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you share error message and part of your view code

Comment: Your List<Car> might be null. Try to initialize it in a constructor or somewhere else

Comment: `model.cars.Name` tries to access `Name` of a `List<Car>`. `List<Car>` doesn't have a `Name`. If you want names of all things contained in the `List<Car>`, iterate over the `List<Car>`.

Comment: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.cars.First().Name)`

Answer (score 0):

I think your Cars is empty . Have you check weather the count is > 0

```
 @ if (Model.Cars!=null &&  Model.Cars.Any())
  {


    @foreach (var item in Model.Cars)
    {
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(i=> i.Name)
    }
  }
```

best practice is to have like this in your model to avoid null reference errors

```
public class Run
{
    public Run()
     {
        cars = new List<Car>()
     }
    public List<Car> cars{get; set;}
    public Bike bike{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: `@Html` helpers work properly if something they try to access is `null`. `i => i.Name` inside a `foreach (var item)` also does not make sense.

Comment: hi @GSerg you are right but I have a if Statement which check if it has any   Cars in it and then looping through it.Updated in my answer as well